# Is logging in via ssh without a password really the same as running a script as root?

Tags: discussion

During the course of review I noticed [How can I avoid having to enter a password for an scp command by hard-coding the password into my script?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1103591/how-can-i-avoid-having-to-enter-a-password-for-an-scp-command-by-hard-coding-the?noredirect=1#comment1819926_1103591) [sudodus](https://askubuntu.com/users/55537/sudodus) asked some good questions in the comments and was providing what looked to me like valuable information. I encouraged an answer, meanwhile this question was closed as a duplicate of [Run Bash Script as Root](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153402/run-bash-script-as-root) which to me doesn't appear to be a very good fit. I've voted to reopen in the hope that a quality answer can be provided. Does this seem to be a course of action the community can support?

Comment: Voted to Reopen...  **;-)**

Comment: FWIW, I voted to close as unclear (but I should have retracted my vote after OP explained) - no way a dupe of that!

Comment: The question is no longer marked as duplicate. I have written an answer :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it's not the same. Clearly this is something the community was willing to take action on as the question was re-opened and a [quality answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1103977/225694) was provided by [sudodus.](https://meta.askubuntu.com/users/55537/sudodus).